# Is there a way to edit the Windows registry from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

My laptop is a Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual-boot setup. I've been experimenting with alternative desktop shells on my Windows partition, such as KDE and [Cairo](http://www.elementsoftware.co.uk/software/cairoshell/).

After setting Cairo as my default shell, I decided to restart my computer and log back into Windows just to make sure everything was working properly. However, after logging in, I found myself left with nothing but the mouse cursor and a blank desktop filled with the default background color.

I know the registry setting I need to change in order to restore Windows Explorer as the default shell from my prior experimentation with KDE, but I obviously can't use `regedit` if I can't load into a working desktop. However, I can still use my Ubuntu partition with no problems.

This has me wondering if there is a way I can mount my Windows partition in Ubuntu and somehow edit the registry from there. How would I go about doing this, and do I need any extra packages for it?

Comment: I don't think so.  Can you boot to the default administrator account for windows 7, run `regedit` and change the keys in the profile of your user?

Comment: Actually, I just now found I could use Task Manager after logging in by Ctrl+Alt+Delete, and then using File > New Task to manually run a dock I was making in GameMaker. From there I can launch pretty much everything else, so at least I can still fix it from Windows. That being said, I'm still curious if the registry can be accessed from Ubuntu, since apparently noone's asked that before.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe that's what you're looking for, "[Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)"(chntpw)

**What is chntpw?**

chntpw is a software utility for resetting or blanking local passwords used by Windows NT, 2000, XP, Vista, 7, and 8.1. It also contains a simple registry editor and hex-editor with which the information contained in a registry file can be browsed and modified under linux/unix.

**How to install?**

You can install it from terminal by running this command:

`sudo apt-get install chntpw`

Or search for "chntpw" in Software Center.

**Additional sources:**

[Using chntpw in Ubuntu to Hack the Windows Registry](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505170011/http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/Hacking%20the%20Windows%20Registry%20with%20chntpw.html)

[Change or Reset Windows Password from a Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/)

Comment: Very Cool.  Good to know.

Comment: Cool...I didn't know `chntpw` included a registry editor.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Well, not exactly. In a number of cases, `chntpw` can only clear (or blank) the password for an account - sometimes it can't actually change the password. Still, it is an awesome tool.

Comment: Note that second to last link is dead but it is archived here https://web.archive.org/web/20120505170011/http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/Hacking%20the%20Windows%20Registry%20with%20chntpw.html